# React Typescript subcomponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, subcomponent

I'm trying to make a React Component with Subcomponents in the style of:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/
which should render one component on the left and one on the right

```
<MyComponent>
   <MyComponent.Left>
      foo
   </MyComponent.Left>
   <MyComponent.Right>
      bar
   </MyComponent.Right>
</MyComponent>
```

My basic strategy has been to create something like this:

```
function MyComponent(props:PropsWithChildren):JSX.Element{
var leftComponent = ???;
var rightComponent = ???;
return 
(<div>
   <div className="this-goes-on-the-right">leftComponent</div>
   <div className="this-goes-on-the-left">rightComponent</div>
</div>);
}

function MyComponent.Left = function MyComponentLeft(props:PropsWithChildren){
   return (<div>props.children</div>);
}
function MyComponent.Right = function MyComponentRight(props:PropsWithChildren){
   return (<div>props.children</div>);
}
```

But I'm lost as to how to figure out which of the children passed to MyComponent is the MyComponent.Left and which is the MyComponent.Right. How can I do this in typescript?

Answer (score 0):

They are using `Object.assign` to assign "sub components".

```
const Card: BsPrefixRefForwardingComponent<'div', CardProps> = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLElement,
  CardProps
>(
  (
    {
      props
    },
    ref,
  ) => {
    return (
      <Component
        ...
      </Component>
    );
  },
);

Card.displayName = 'Card';
Card.propTypes = propTypes;
Card.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Object.assign(Card, {
  Img: CardImg,
  Title: CardTitle,
  Subtitle: CardSubtitle,
  Body: CardBody,
  Link: CardLink,
  Text: CardText,
  Header: CardHeader,
  Footer: CardFooter,
  ImgOverlay: CardImgOverlay,
});
```

[Source](https://github.dev/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/7f633bf31ed4771c97904df4bb9567900ad4e96c/src/Card.tsx#L76)

Comment: Can you explain what that means and how it helps achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

1. There are multiple ways probably to approach what you are aiming at. The most basic could be to set some names to the components and check each child for it's name ([react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#displayname)) but I would not recommend this.
2. Rather you should style your `MyComponent.Left` and `MyComponent.Right` properly so they are shown the desired way no matter of the order they are passed to the `MyComponent`'s children.

Sketch up of what I mean:

```
function MyComponent(props:PropsWithChildren):JSX.Element{
  return (
    <div>{props.children}</div>
  );
}

function MyComponent.Left = function MyComponentLeft(props:PropsWithChildren){
   return (<div className="this-goes-on-the-left">props.children</div>);
}
function MyComponent.Right = function MyComponentRight(props:PropsWithChildren){
   return (<div className="this-goes-on-the-right">props.children</div>);
}
```

The implementation of the classes which style the nested component could be based on flex-box rules, or floating or whatever suits your use case.

3. One more option which is slightly off your example but might be useful is to pass the components as props, not children like:

```
function MyComponent(props:PropsWithChildren):JSX.Element{
  return (
    <div>
       <div className="this-goes-on-the-right">{props.right}</div>
       <div className="this-goes-on-the-left">{props.left}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can your option 2 only works for the case that all the children are contained within the same parent <div> correct? This matches my provided example, however there may be situations where this is not the case. Your option 3 is how i have been doing this up until now, where I found that Parent.Child notation seems to be the "standard" way of doing things

Comment: Yes, the second option will work if they are both within the same parent element. You just have to decide how you want your components to work - usually this notation is used when components are not for general use but are strictly dependent on the main component and their behavior is related to the concept of the main one. Thus you always have some limitations how to group or order the components which is okay. If you have in mind another use case - please provide an example.